# Where can I find a Meteor Strike skill book?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I'm trying to get the Meteor Strike skill. So far I haven't looted one, and none of the spell vendors seem to sell it.

I've heard people claim that the vendors in Silverglen sell it once the characters reach level 16, but that doesn't seem to be true.

I'm currently in the Phantom Forest region, completing the *Hunt in Hunter's Edge* quest. My characters are around level 17. I'm playing the Enhanced Edition on PS4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your characters are level 16?

All magic/skill book vendors should be selling it upon being level 16.

[You should be able to find the books](https://www.reddit.com/r/DivinityOriginalSin/comments/2bz6c0/can_anyone_help_me_with_skill_books_spoilers/) at Silverglen inn (a bunch of vendors sitting together), the pyro elemental in your Homestead or Arhu (2nd floor of legion HQ)

[You need Pyrokinetic level 4 to use it.](https://divinityoriginalsin.wiki.fextralife.com/Meteor+Shower) It will cost +2 AP for each level below that. It is also recommended to have 12 intelligence, each level below will reduce the status effect chance by 10%.

[Note](https://divinity.fandom.com/wiki/Meteor_Shower): In this game, the skill book itself is called "Meteor Strike" but the skill is Meteor Shower.

Comment: I'll double-check again later today with all my characters and the various vendors. Please note that the first link you provided refers to Divinity Original Sin 2.

Comment: You're right, I updated the link and level information. The locations should still remain the same - your best bet is just going to the fire elemental in homestead

Comment: I just checked; all of my characters are level 17, one of them has Pyrokinetic level 5. Neither Arhu nor the vendors in Silverglen (Hassar is the one who sells pyro books) have the book, however, the fire elemental in the homestead does. I don’t know if this is somehow irregular, but I’ll mark this as the correct answer, since it led me to the right place.

Comment: The other two might just be chance, it's been a bit since I played this one. I do remember the Homestead elementals always having almost all of their respective skill books all the time.